# How can I create a script that prompts a user for a response with a visual countdown timeout?

Tags: scripts, input-method

I see this sort of behavior many scripts, where the script displays multiple options for the user (or often the case y/N) and waits for the user to make their selection by pressing a key and then pressing *enter* to continue in the script.  As well as asking for a selection, the script also displays a countdown message, such as "10 secs".

After displaying the options and the waiting period length, the "countdown" text starts decreasing until it hits 0 at which point the default value is returned-- assuming the user did not make a selection.

I'm fairly certain this does not use **readkey** to monitor presses because sometimes the prompt could be asking for a string value.  The following code is close to what I want, but I'd like to see the countdown timer.

```
#!/bin/bash

TMOUT=5
echo -n "Enter you username: "
read username

if [[ -z $username ]]; then
        # No username provide
        username="Not Set"
        echo "Timeout, Run this script again and set your valid username..."
fi
```

Comment: I just realized I could examine  one of the scripts in question, but I don't know any off hand that has a countdown as I described.

Comment: How about [this one](https://www.putorius.net/how-to-make-countdown-timer-in-bash.html)?